# Stack Overflow on DLL file

Tags: c#, dll

I am a beginner programmer, learning about C#. I keep getting a stack overflow error on my .dll when I link it with my main .cs in Visual Studio and start debugging. My code for the .dll is below:

```
// Begin namespace LibEmployee1
namespace LibEmployee1
{

/****************************************************************/
/* 1. Class Employee                                            */ 
/****************************************************************/

public class Employee
{

private const double FICA_RATE      = 0.07;
private const double FED_TAX_RATE   = 0.22;
private const double STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.05;

private int    id;
private string lastName,firstName;
private Date   hireDate;
private double rate;
private double hours;

public Employee() // Default constructor
{
  this.id        = 0;
  this.lastName  = "";  
  this.firstName = "";
  this.hireDate  = new Date();
  this.rate      = 0.0;
  this.hours     = 0.0;
}

public Employee(int idValue, string lastNameValue, // Initializing constructor
                string firstNameValue, Date hireDateValue, 
                double rateValue, double hoursValue)
{
  this.ID        = idValue;
  this.LastName  = lastNameValue;  
  this.FirstName = firstNameValue;
  this.HireDate  =  new Date(hireDateValue);
  this.Rate      = rateValue;
  this.Hours     = hoursValue;
}

public Employee(int idValue, string lastNameValue, // Initializing constructor
                string firstNameValue, int hireYearValue,
                int hireMonthValue, int hireDayValue,  
                double rateValue, double hoursValue)
{
  this.ID        = idValue;
  this.LastName  = lastNameValue;  
  this.FirstName = firstNameValue;
  this.hireDate  = new Date(hireYearValue,hireMonthValue,hireDayValue);
  this.Rate      = rateValue;
  this.Hours     = hoursValue;
}


public Employee(int idValue, string lastNameValue, // Initializing constructor
                string firstNameValue, string hireDateString, 
                double rateValue, double hoursValue)
{
  this.ID        = idValue;
  this.LastName  = lastNameValue;  
  this.FirstName = firstNameValue;
  this.hireDate  = Date.Parse(hireDateString);
  this.Rate      = rateValue;
  this.Hours     = hoursValue;
}

public Employee(Employee sourceEmployee) // Copy constructor
{
  this.hireDate = new Date();
  this.Copy(sourceEmployee);
} 

public int ID   // Define read/write ID property
{
  get
  {
    return this.id;
  }
  set
  {
    if ((value >= 1) && (value <= 9999))
      this.id = value;
    else
      ProcessError(String.Format("{0} can not be assigned to an ID property\n\nAbort?", value));
  }
}

public string LastName  // Define read/write LastName property
{
  get
  {
    return this.lastName;
  }
  set
  {
    this.lastName = value.Trim();
  }
}

public string FirstName  // Define read/write FirstName property
{
  get
  {
    return this.firstName;
  }
  set
  {
    this.firstName = value.Trim();
  }
}

public Date HireDate  // Define read/write HireDate property
{
  get
  {
    return this.HireDate;
  }
  set
  {
    this.HireDate.Copy(value);
  }
}

public double Rate // Define read/write Rate property
{
  get
  {
    return this.Rate;
  }
  set
  {
    if ((value >= 0) && (value <= 9999.0))
      this.Rate = value;
    else
      ProcessError(String.Format("{0} can not be assigned to the Rate property\n\nAbort?", value));
  }
}

public double Hours // Define read/write Hours property
{
  get
  {
    return this.hours;
  }
  set
  {
    if ((value >= 0) && (value <= 300.0))
      this.hours = value;
    else
      ProcessError(String.Format("{0} can not be assigned to the Hours property\n\nAbort?", value));
  }
}

public double Earnings
{
  get
  {
    return Math.Round(this.Rate * this.hours, 2);
  }

}

public double FICA  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    return Math.Round(this.Earnings * .07, 2);
  }
}

public double FedTax  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    return Math.Round(this.Earnings * .22, 2);
  }
}

public double StateTax  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    return Math.Round(this.Earnings * .05, 2);
  }
}

public double NetPay  // Define result property
{
  get
  {
    return Math.Round(this.Earnings - (this.FICA + this.FedTax + this.StateTax), 2);
  }
}

public string this[int propertyIndex]   // Define readonly indexer property
{
  get
  {
    string returnValue = "";
    switch (propertyIndex)
    {
      case 0: returnValue = this.id.ToString("d4"); break;
      case 1: returnValue = this.lastName; break;
      case 2: returnValue = this.firstName; break;
      case 3: returnValue = this.hireDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); break;
      case 4: returnValue = this.Earnings.ToString("f2"); break;
      case 5: returnValue = this.FICA.ToString("f2"); break;
      case 6: returnValue = this.FedTax.ToString("f2"); break;
      case 7: returnValue = this.StateTax.ToString("f2"); break;
      case 8: returnValue = this.NetPay.ToString("f2"); break;
      default: ProcessError(String.Format("{0} is an invalid " +
                            "propertyIndex value for the Employee " +
                            "class this[] indexer\n\nAbort?", propertyIndex)); break;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
}

public string this[string propertyName]   // Define readonly indexer property
{
  get
  {
    string returnValue = "";

    switch (propertyName.ToUpper())
    {
      case "ID"       :          returnValue = this.id.ToString("d4");        break;
      case "LASTNAME" : case "LAST NAME": returnValue = this.lastName;        break;
      case "FIRSTNAME": returnValue = this.firstName;                         break;
      case "HIREDATE" : returnValue = this.hireDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");   break;
      case "EARNINGS" : returnValue = this.Earnings.ToString("f2");           break;
      case "FICA"     : returnValue = this.FICA.ToString("f2");               break;
      case "FEDTAX"   : returnValue = this.FedTax.ToString("f2");             break;
      case "STATETAX" : returnValue = this.StateTax.ToString("f2");           break;
      case "NETPAY"   : returnValue = this.NetPay.ToString("f2");             break;
      default: ProcessError(String.Format("{0} is an invalid " +
                            "propertyName value for the Student " +
                            "class this[] indexer\n\nAbort?", propertyName)); break;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
}

public void Copy(Employee sourceEmployee) // Copy method
{
  this.id = sourceEmployee.id; this.rate = sourceEmployee.rate;
  this.lastName = sourceEmployee.lastName; this.firstName = sourceEmployee.firstName;
  this.hours = sourceEmployee.hours; 
  this.hireDate.Copy(sourceEmployee.hireDate);
}

public Employee Clone()
{
  return new Employee
(this);
}

public int CompareTo(Employee employee)          
{                                         
  return this.id.CompareTo(employee.id);
}

public static int CompareIDs(Employee employee1, Employee employee2)
{
  return employee1.id.CompareTo(employee2.id);
}

public static int CompareNames(Employee employee1, Employee employee2)
{
  string string1 = employee1.lastName + employee1.firstName + employee1.id.ToString("d4");
  string string2 = employee2.lastName + employee2.firstName + employee2.id.ToString("d4");
  return string1.CompareTo(string2);
}

public static int CompareHireDates(Employee employee1, Employee employee2)
{
  string string1 = employee1.lastName + employee1.firstName + employee1.hireDate.ToString("");
  string string2 = employee2.lastName + employee2.firstName + employee2.hireDate.ToString("");
  return string1.CompareTo(string2);
}

public static int CompareEarnings(Employee employee1, Employee employee2)
{
  string string1 = employee1.lastName + employee1.firstName + employee1.Earnings.ToString("");
  string string2 = employee2.lastName + employee2.firstName + employee2.Earnings.ToString("");
  return string1.CompareTo(string2);
}

public static Employee Parse(string stringValue)
{
  string[] words;
  Employee employee = new Employee();

  stringValue = StringMethods.SpaceDelimit(stringValue);
  words       = stringValue.Split(' ');
  employee.ID        = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
  employee.LastName  = words[1];
  employee.FirstName = words[2];
  employee.HireDate  = Date.Parse(words[3]);
  employee.Rate      = Double.Parse(words[4]);
  employee.Hours     = Double.Parse(words[5]);
  return employee;
}

public override string ToString() 
{
  return String.Format("{0:d4} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,10:MM/dd/yyyy} {4,7:f} {5,7:f} {6,7:f} {7,7:f} {8,7:f} {9,7:f} {10,7:f}",
                       this.id, this.lastName, this.firstName, this.HireDate,
                       this.rate, this.hours, this.Earnings, this.FICA, this.FedTax,
                       this.StateTax, this.NetPay);
}

private void ProcessError(string message)
{
  DialogResult result;

  result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                           MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
  if (result==DialogResult.Yes)
    ConsoleApp.Exit();
}

} // End class Employee

/****************************************************************/
/* 2. Class EmployeeList : IEnumerable                          */ 
/****************************************************************/

public class EmployeeList : IEnumerable
{
public delegate int CompareDelegate(Employee employee1, Employee employee2);

private int        capacity;  // Data member
private int        count;     // Data member
private Employee[] items;     // Data member

public EmployeeList() // Default constructor
{
  this.capacity = 1;
  this.count    = 0;
  this.items    = new Employee[1];
} 

private EmployeeList(int capacityValue) // Initializing constructor
{
  if (capacityValue>=1)      
  { 
    this.capacity = capacityValue;
    this.count    = 0;
    this.items    = new Employee[capacityValue];
  }
  else
    ProcessError(String.Format("{0} can not be the capacity of an EmployeeList object\n\nAbort?",capacityValue));
}

public EmployeeList(EmployeeList sourceList) // Copy constructor
{
  this.Copy(sourceList);
}

public int Count // Define read-only Count property
{
  get
  {
    return this.count;
  }
}

public Employee this[int index]   // Define read/write this[] indexer property
{ 
   get
  {  
    if ((index>=1) && (index<=count))
     return this.items[index-1];
    else
    {
      ProcessError(String.Format("EmployeeList [] Get index must be between 1 and {0}\n\nAbort?",this.count));
      return default(Employee);
    }
  }
  set
  {
    if ((index >= 1) && (index <= this.count))
      this.items[index - 1] = value;
    else
      ProcessError(String.Format("EmployeeList [] Set index must be between 1 and {0}\n\nAbort?", this.count));
  }
}

public bool Empty // Return true (false) if list is (not) empty
{
  get
  {
    return (this.count == 0);
  }
}

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()      // IEnumerable Interface Implementation:
{                                       // Declaration of the GetEnumerator() method,
  for (int i=1; i<=this.count; i++)     // which is needed to give meaning to the "foreach"
    yield return this[i];               // control construct.
} 

public void Clear()  // Remove all list elements
{
  this.capacity = 1;
  this.count = 0;
  this.items = new Employee[1];
}

public void Copy(EmployeeList sourceList)  // This approach is correct
{
  this.Clear();
  foreach (Employee employee in sourceList)
    this.Add(employee.Clone());
}

public EmployeeList Clone()
{
  return new EmployeeList(this); 
}

private void IncreaseCapacity()
{
  EmployeeList tempList;

  tempList = new EmployeeList(2 * this.capacity);
  foreach (Employee employee in this)
    tempList.Add(employee);
  this.capacity = tempList.capacity;
  this.count = tempList.count;
  this.items = tempList.items;
}

public void Add(Employee employee)
{
  this.InsertAt(this.count+1, employee);
}

public void InsertAt(int position, Employee employee)
{
  int i;

  if ((position >= 1) && (position <= this.count + 1))
  {
    if (this.count == this.capacity)
      this.IncreaseCapacity();
    this.count++;
    for (i = this.count; i > position; i--)
      this[i] = this[i - 1];
    this[position] = employee;
  }
  else
    ProcessError(String.Format("EmployeeList InsertAt index must be between 1 and {0}\n\nAbort?", this.count + 1));
}

public Employee RemoveAt(int position)
{
  int i;
  Employee employee = null;

  if ((position >= 1) && (position <= this.count))
  {
    employee = this[position];
    for (i = position; i < this.count; i++)
      this[i] = this[i + 1];
    this.count--;
  }
  else
    ProcessError(String.Format("EmployeeList RemoveAt index must be between 1 and {0}\n\nAbort?", this.count));
  return employee;
}

private void ProcessError(string message)
{
  DialogResult result;

  result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                           MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
  if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    ConsoleApp.Exit();
}

public void Reverse()
{
  int i;
  Employee tempValue;

  for (i = 1; i <= this.count / 2; i++)
  {
    tempValue = this[i];
    this[i] = this[this.count + 1 - i];
    this[this.count + 1 - i] = tempValue;
  }
}

public int Locate(Employee employee) // Locate and return the list index 
{                                    // of data in the list.
  int listIndex = 1;                 


  while ((listIndex <= this.count) && (this[listIndex].CompareTo(employee) < 0))
    listIndex++;
  if (listIndex > this.count)
    listIndex = ~listIndex;

  else if (this[listIndex].CompareTo(employee) > 0)
    listIndex = ~listIndex;
  return listIndex;
}

public int Locate(Employee employee, CompareDelegate compareMethod) // Locate and return the list index 
{                                                                   // of data in the list.
  int listIndex = 1;                                              // Uses a CompareDelegate method.   

  while ((listIndex <= this.count) && (compareMethod(this[listIndex], employee) < 0))
    listIndex++;
  if (listIndex > this.count)
    listIndex = ~listIndex;
  else if (compareMethod(this[listIndex], employee) > 0)
    listIndex = ~listIndex;
  return listIndex;
}

public void Sort()   // Uses the Employee class CompareTo method  
{
  int i, j, k;
  Employee temp;

  for (i = 1; i <= (this.count - 1); i++)
  {
    k = i;
    for (j = (i + 1); j <= this.count; j++)
     if (this[j].CompareTo(this[k]) < 0)
        k = j;
    if (k > i)
    {
      temp = this[k];
      this[k] = this[i];
      this[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}

public void Sort(CompareDelegate compareMethod)  // Uses a CompareDelegate method.  
{
  int i, j, k;
  Employee temp;

  for (i = 1; i <= (this.count - 1); i++)
  {
    k = i;
    for (j = (i + 1); j <= this.count; j++)
      if (compareMethod(this[j], this[k]) < 0)
        k = j;
    if (k > i)
    {
      temp = this[k];
      this[k] = this[i];
      this[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}

public double Total(string propertyName)
{
  double total = 0.0;

  foreach (Employee employee in this)
    total += Double.Parse(employee[propertyName]);
  return total;
}

public double Mean(string propertyName)
{
  return this.Total(propertyName) / this.Count;
}

public double Max(string propertyName)
{
  int i;
  double max = Double.Parse(this[1][propertyName]);

  for (i = 2; i <= this.Count; i++)
    if (Double.Parse(this[i][propertyName]) > max)
      max = Double.Parse(this[i][propertyName]);
  return max;
}

public double Min(string propertyName)
{
  int i;
  double min = Double.Parse(this[1][propertyName]);

  for (i = 2; i <= this.Count; i++)
    if (Double.Parse(this[i][propertyName]) < min)
      min = Double.Parse(this[i][propertyName]);
  return min;
}

public int AssignID()
{
  int returnValue = 1;

  if (this.count>0)
    returnValue =  (int) this.Max("ID") + 1;
  return returnValue;
}

public void Input(StreamReader fileIn)
{
  string lineIn;

  while ((lineIn=fileIn.ReadLine())!=null)
    this.Add(Employee.Parse(lineIn));
}

public void PrintReport(StreamWriter fileOut, string orderDescriptor)
{
  int indent = (63 - orderDescriptor.Length) / 2;

  orderDescriptor = "".PadLeft(indent) + orderDescriptor;
  fileOut.WriteLine("                        Employee Report                         ");
  fileOut.WriteLine(orderDescriptor);
  fileOut.WriteLine("                          {0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Date.Today);
  fileOut.WriteLine();
  fileOut.WriteLine("                          Jon Ernst                             ");
  if (!this.Empty)
  {
    fileOut.WriteLine(" ID     Last Name      First Name       Hired    Earnings    FICA    Fed Tax  State Tax  Net Pay ");
    fileOut.WriteLine("---- --------------- --------------- ---------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------");
    foreach (Employee employee in this)
      fileOut.WriteLine("{0:d4} {1,-15} {2,-15} {3,10:MM/dd/yyyy} {4,7:f} {5,7:f} {6,7:f} {7,7:f} {8,7:f}",
                        employee.ID, employee.LastName, employee.FirstName, employee.HireDate,
                        employee.Earnings, employee.FICA, employee.FedTax, employee.StateTax, employee.NetPay);
    fileOut.WriteLine("                                                     --------- -------- --------- --------- ---------");
    fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-52} {1,7:f} {2,7:f} {3,7:f} {4,7:f} {5,7:f}", "Mean", this.Mean("Earnings"), this.Mean("FICA"), this.Mean("Fed Tax"), this.Mean("State Tax"), this.Mean("Net Pay"));
    fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-52} {1,7:f} {2,7:f} {3,7:f} {4,7:f} {5,7:f}", "Maximum", this.Max("Earnings"), this.Max("FICA"), this.Max("Fed Tax"), this.Max("State Tax"), this.Max("Net Pay"));
    fileOut.WriteLine("{0,-52} {1,7:f} {2,7:f} {3,7:f} {4,7:f} {5,7:f}", "Minimum", this.Min("Earnings"), this.Min("FICA"), this.Min("Fed Tax"), this.Min("State Tax"), this.Min("Net Pay"));
    fileOut.WriteLine();
    fileOut.WriteLine("Count = {0}", this.Count);
  }
  else
    fileOut.WriteLine("The list is empty.");
  fileOut.WriteLine();
}

} // End class EmployeeList

} // End namespace LibEmployee1
```

Visual Studio is pointing out the stack overflow error at this method:

```
public Date HireDate  // Define read/write HireDate property
{
  get
  {  **<=== visual studio points the overflow error specifically to this line**
    return this.HireDate;  
  }
  set
  {
    this.HireDate.Copy(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is part of a program that is supposed to provide a payroll report on a text file

Comment: Your return is calling the getter of the property itself. This causes infinite recursion leading to your stack overflow.

Comment: The HireDate property getter returns the value of the HireDate property.  Whose property getter returns the value of the HireDate property.  Whose property getter returns the value of the HireDate property.  Whose prop.... Kabooooom!

Comment: In your default constructor you're setting the private properties (good) - in your other constructors you're directly setting the public ones (bad) - might not fix your immediate issue... just pointing out :)

Comment: To help yourself with noticing this sort of stuff, define private property names with an `_`, such as `private int _id;` - that way you, nor anybody else, will get them confused; it's also the usual convention.

Comment: Not sure why anybody would downvote the question - seems a perfectly acceptable one to me.

Comment: @Darren wagering a guess, it would be because this question (stack overflows with recursive getter/setter calls) has been asked before more than a few times.

Comment: When you're so new and fresh at this game though it's not easy to extract from the answers to fix your own problem. He didn't know he had a recursive getter/setter - perhaps wasn't even aware of what it even meant until he asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer right there in your code, in your `HireDate` property, you're returning the value of your `HireDate` property, which in turn will return the value of your `HireDate` property, and so on..! You probably want to return the value of the backing field.

```
public DateTime HireDate
{
    get
    {
        return this.hireDate;
    }
    set
    {
        this.hireDate = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity problem.  You're recursively calling the property getter.  return this.hireDate
Also, no need to copy the date in the setter.  It is a value type.